# Is there a way to configure the width of columns in a table by the number of columns?

Tags: php, css, mysql

I am creating a table with a foreach loop in php that creates the columns. Is there a possibility to give the columns an even width like 3 columns -> columnwidth 33%, 4 columns -> 25%, 5 columns -> 20% and so on? Right now it feels like the widths of the columns are random.

*some code if you need it:*

PHP/HTML

```
echo '<tr>';
    $permgroups = $perms->getPermissiongroups();
    foreach ($permgroups as $group) {
        if ($group != "user_ID") {
            echo '<th>'.$group.'</th>';
        }
    }
echo '</tr>';
```

CSS

```
.structure_content table {
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    line-height: 30px;
    background: #BDBDBD;
    width: 100%;
    float: right;
    border-top: 1px solid #CEDADC;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #CEDADC;
}

.structure_content th {
    font-size: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just give your table `table-layout:fixed`....

```css
table {
  table-layout:fixed;
    width:100%;
 margin-bottom: 1em;
}

td {
  padding:.5em;
  border:1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Is there a possibilty to break the rule for one specifig column, e.g. every column is the same width, except for the last one?